# Некорректное выделение памяти по размеру файла

Tags: c, malloc

Здравствуйте. По ходу выполнения задачи столкнулся с проблемами.

Необходимо создать динамический массив, в который позже будет записываться посимвольно текст из файла. С помощью этого узнал количество символов:

```
while ((a = fgetc(myfile)) != EOF)
    ++size;
```

И выделил необходимую память для массива:

```
text = (char*)malloc(size * sizeof(char));
```

Однако, выполняемые проверки показывают, что выделяется неправильное количество памяти. И далее цикл для присвоения символов из строки массиву не выполняется.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, где ошибка.

Полный вариант кода:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
FILE *myfile;
char *text, a;
unsigned size=0, i=0;
myfile = fopen ("input.txt", "r");
while ((a = fgetc(myfile)) != EOF)
    ++size;
printf("%d \n", size);
text=(char*) malloc(size*sizeof(char));
printf("%lu \n", sizeof(char));
printf("%lu \n", sizeof(text));
while ((text[i] = fgetc(myfile)) != EOF) {
    if (text[i] == '\n') {
        text[i] = '\0';
        printf("%s \n",text);
        i = 0;
    }
    else i++;
}
free(text);
fclose(myfile);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> С помощью этого узнал кол-во символов в файле:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238603/how-can-i-get-a-files-size-in-c

А ошибка в том, что после подсчета количества символов не перемещаете [указатель позиции в файле снова в начало](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_rewind.htm).

Comment: @Halva, `sizeof(text)` возвращает **размер переменной текст** (т.е. указателя), а вовсе не памяти на которую он указывает. И во-вторых (тоже очень важно для чтения файлов), при вычислении длины файла (безусловно, абсурдный способ для Вашего случая) Вы читаете символы в переменную типа **char**, а правильно считывать их в **переменную типа** ***int*** (это важно, поскольку у Вас прочитанный символ с кодом 0xff (например, `я` в кодировке cp1251) будет равен EOF (это int со значением -1))

Answer (score 2):

1. Файл нужно открывать в двоичном режиме (`fopen("input.txt", "rb")`). Иначе будут неточно считаться переводы строк.
2. Длину файла вычислять побайтным чтением - это э... Мягко говоря странно. Во-первых, есть пара [fseek()/ftell()](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=ftell&category=3&russian=0). Во-вторых - [stat()/lstat()](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=stat&category=3&russian=5)

**Вариант 1**:

```
FILE * f = fopen("input.txt", "rb");
fseek(f, 0L, SEEK_END);
/* в filesize будет  длина файла */
long filesize = ftell(f);
/* переставили указатель в начало */
fseek(f, 0L, SEEK_SET);
/*
 * выделяем память, читаем.
 */
fclose(f);
```

**Вариант 2**:

```
struct stat statbuf;
stat( "input.txt", &statbuf );
/* теперь в statbuf.st_size содержится размер файла */
```

Понятное дело, везде нужно проверять ошибки. А остальных несуразностей в коде я пока не касался (например, нет никакого смысла в выражении `size*sizeof(char)`, так как `sizeof(char)` всегда 1; зачем нужно выводить `sizeof(char)` и `sizeof(text)` - непонятно, и т.д.). Ну и выделять буфер размером с файл для его построчного чтения - это совсем не нужное дело.

Comment: даже `fseek()/ftell()` лучше не использовать для определения размера . А если будет открыт не файл на диске , а именованый каннал  или  сокет . Там нет размера.